# Radio button onclick insert value to href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to insert the url from an onlick event in the the radio buttonsto the href link but it not working. Here’s I have so far.

```
<input type="radio" name="orderID" value="1"  onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('editBTN').href='forms/editForm.cfm?orderID ='&this.value">

<input type="radio" name=" orderID " value="2" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('editBTN').href='forms/editForm.cfm?orderID ='&this.value">
```

Etc…

The link below href should change depending on which radio button is clicked.

```
<a href="" id="editBTN"> Edit Order</a>
```

The above script returns the current url with `“localhost/myApp/0”` at the end. If I remove this (`'forms/editForm.cfm?orderID='&`) from the radio button it correctly return the orderId.

I would like this result `localhost/myApp/forms/editForm.cfm?orderID=1`. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user - I cleaned it up a bit, but not sure those URL code blocks at the end are exactly what they're supposed to be, can you fix them to exactly what you're seeing? (For future questions...use the 1010 button up top when you're code is selected for formatting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript uses `+` to concatenate strings, not `&`:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('editBTN').href=
         'forms/editForm.cfm?orderID ='+this.value"
```

(line break added for readability)
should work.

You can lose the `javascript:` prefix, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You listed jquery as one of your question tags. I'd simply place the following script onto my page and attach the click event on the radio's to push their value into the appropriate button attribute.

```
$('input[name=orderID]').click(function(e) {

$('#editBTN').attr('href', 'forms/editForm.cfm?orderID ='+$(this).val());

});
```

Comment: +1 just remember that this needs to be put in jQuery's "document ready" event.

Comment: @user281867, no problem, glad it helped. Please mark the answer correct if you are using this solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the & before this.value should be a +